# Venus GPS 1PPS configuration

Tags: gps, documentation

I have a Venus634LPx GPS on a breakout board from SparkFun. Read more about it in [my previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299424).

The configuration program gives me the option to configure "1PPS Timing":

[image]

Here I can choose between "Survey", "Static" and "PVT" (Position, Velocity and Time). The [Venus838LPx datasheet](http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/content/Venus838LPx-T_DS_v4.pdf) talks about these modes, but not the Venus634LPx datasheet.

- What do these modes mean? I find the datasheet confusing.
- Is it something unique to the 838, or does the 634 also have these modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted SkyTraq directly, and they said:

> [The Venus634LPx is] a very old product that does not [support the] precision timing related functions you ask [for]. You might consider this instead: http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/ns-t-precision-timing-frequency-generation-gps-receiver/

So the options in my question is not applicable to the `Venus634LPx` chipset. The device they suggested uses the `Venus822A` chipset.

Still no answer about what these "precision timing related functions" actually mean.